# POST json object as a variable names json in POST in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

The server needs a variable named json with a value of a json object.
I can convert an `NSDictionary` into a `JSON` object with the form of NSData (*which is a black box to me*).

My question is, how do I take that black box of NSData and assign it to a variable json, and then post it to the server?

As a side question, is it me or is it odd that the server is asking for such a format?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not just you. That is a bit strange, but the good news is it can be done!

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSData *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&jsonError];
if (!jsonError) {
    NSMutableData *postBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[@"json=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:jsonObject];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. mapquest also has a similar api. http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE]&json={locations:["State College,PA","Lancaster,PA"]}